# Why does Bootstrap not working with chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

im new to web-development and front-end i downloaded bootstrap and puted some code to test it it works fine with firefox but not in chrome it appears like a non styled html code so if there any solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

the result in chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Since you are loading CSS and JavaScript file from the same origin where the HTML file is in, you need to omit the `integrity` and `crossorigin` property in `<link>` and `<script>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```